# How to get previous tag in git

Tags: git, tags, version, command-line-interface

I want to be able to roll back to a previous git tag without having to know what the current tag is or what the previous tag is.

I know how to get the latest tag:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
```

but how would I get the tag right before it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't find any resources online for doing this, so here is what I found to work:

```
 git describe --abbrev=0 --tags `git rev-list --tags --skip=1  --max-count=1`
```

The subcommand gets the hash of one recent tag. The `--skip=1` means the "latest" tag will be skipped and the "previous" tag to the latest will be returned.

If current tag is `1.1.5`, the previous tag number returned would be `1.1.4`

Comment: What if the tag given in the sub-command `git rev-list --tags --skip=1  --max-count=1` is in another branch? I feel that the command is error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags --exclude="$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)"`

### Long story

You can always use the `~` syntax, for example, here's how I'd do it:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags "$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)~"
```

to be sure there aren't tags in different branches, you can check that it's equal to the following command:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags "$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)^"
```

##### UPD 2022-05-16

I went through `describe` help and it has the following argument:

```
--exclude <pattern>
    Do not consider tags matching the given glob(7) pattern, excluding the "refs/tags/" prefix.
```

So, the easiest way to get the previous tag is:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags --exclude="$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)" "$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)"
```

##### UPD 2022-08-27

As [Petr Plenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818419/how-to-get-previous-tag-in-git/72125681?noredirect=1#comment129605426_72125681) found, the latest argument can be omitted and it gives the same result, so it's just

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags --exclude="$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)"
```

Comment: Nice catch with update. But why not just  `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags --exclude="$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)"` ?

Comment: Well, they give the same result, so the latest argument can be omitted for sure :+1: